# Boxplot with a bolean column and a Int value

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn

I would like to create a boxplot of the distribution of the variable duration according to whether the film belongs to the category Dramas or (true or false)

Unfortunately these two options do not take into account whether the in_Dramas column is true or false...

Notice that the two columns are in the same DataFrame

```
movies.boxplot(column= 'in_drama', by='duree', figsize= (7,7)); 

# sns.catplot(x="in_drama", y="duree" , kind="box", data=movies);
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the pandas boxplot, you can set `by='in_drama'` and `column='duree'` to get x-values of `in_drama == False` and `in_drama == True`, and boxplots taking into account the `duree` column:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

movies = pd.DataFrame({'in_drama': [False, False, False, False, False, True, True, True, True, True],
                       'durée': [95, 118, 143, 89, 91, 145, 168, 193, 139, 141]})
movies.boxplot(by='in_drama', column='durée', figsize=(7, 7))
plt.show()
```

The seaborn plot should also work. As only one subplot is needed, `sns.boxplot` can be used directly.

```py
sns.set()
sns.boxplot(x="in_drama", y="durée", data=movies)
```

At the left the pandas boxplot, at the right seaborn:

[image: pandas vs seaborn boxplot]